# Can botulinum toxin be grown or kept from denaturing in an UNWRAPPED 50 pound hay bale?

Tags: cell-biology, toxicology, growth-media, bacterial-toxins

[Botulinum toxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) is the neurotoxin protein created when botulism spores grow. The requirements for growth and/or for keeping the toxin from denaturing would seem to be very difficult to create in bale of hay.

There are well documented [incidents of botulism in horses](http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/livestock/horses/facts/info_botulism.htm) who are eating hay, all the references I found were centered around hay in large plastic wrapped bales.

I have been [involved in an event](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4407) where the presumed DX is botulism secondary to ingestion from hay from last year.  In this case the hay is second cutting timothy hay (making it 6 plus months old), in rectangular 50 pound (22 kg) bales that are not wrapped, have been barn kept, and when purchased from the vendor where stacked in rows 4 feet wide, by 6 feet (2 meters) high. The bale then spent more then a week on an shelf (chrome platted heavy wire) with good air circulation.

Three pet [house rabbits](http://rabbit.org/) appear to have been effected. with 2 dead and one recovering from a case of descending paralysis.  Several tests are underway, but my understanding is that it may be difficult to conclusively show either the botulism in the rabbits, or significant presence of 'botulinum toxin' or 'clostridium botulinum' in the hay (samples from the mangers of effected animals are being tested).

Is it possible to logically conclude that Botulinum toxin could, or could not, be created and/or survive in a bale of hay meeting the above criteria?

**Note**

If there is an awareness of a plant based neurotoxin that would cause similar symptoms that may be growing in the hay field please offer that in an answer at [Gardnening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11007).

Comment: It's been a long time since I knew the ins and outs of botulinum toxin, but I do seem to recall that it's pretty resilient. Botulism is pretty distinct as far as symptom progression. I'll see if I can do more research and return.

Comment: @MCM, thanks it would be really great if you could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an addendum to Spinorial's answer, and after some research, the Center for Food Security and Public Health *specifically* lists hay / grass / **decaying vegetable matter** as a potential source for *C. botulinum* growth in their (very informative) [Botulism PDF](http://www.cfsph.iastate.edu/Factsheets/pdfs/botulism.pdf).

> All species of Clostridium can produce spores, dormant 
>   forms  of  the  organism  that  are  highly  resistant  to 
>   disinfectants,  heat  and  environmental  conditions  that  kill 
>   vegetative  cells. These  spores  can  survive  for many  years 
>   until  favorable  conditions  allow  them  to  germinate  and 
>   grow. C. botulinum spores are common in the environment...
>   ...
>   Different  strains  or  groups  of  C.  botulinum  may  have 
>   somewhat  different  requirements. For  instance,  the  acidity 
>   necessary  to  inhibit C. botulinum  type C strains  is reported 
>   to be pH 5.1 to 5.6, but other organisms can survive a lower 
>   pH. Each group also has an optimal, minimal and maximal 
>   temperature  for  growth.  For  example,  some  group  II 
>   organisms  may  be  able  to  grow  in  foods  at  refrigeration 
>   temperatures  (3-4°C/ 37-39°F), but group  I organisms  and 
>   type  C  toxin-producing  strains  are  inhibited.  Because  C. 
>   botulinum  does  not  compete  well  with  other 
>   microorganisms,  growth  is  more  likely  to  occur  if  other 
>   bacteria  and  molds  have  been  killed  or  inhibited.  C. 
>   botulinum  spores  can  survive  cooking  and  some  food-
>   processing  conditions  that  kill  vegetative  cells,  then 
>   germinate and grow in the cooked food.

As for your question...

> Is it possible to logically conclude that Botulinum toxin could, or could not, be created and/or survive in a bale of hay meeting the above criteria?

Could the toxin survive? Probably. The toxin itself isn't particularly hearty, **BUT**...

Could the *spores* survive (and go on to create the toxin)? **Definitely**. The spores survive direct heating/boiling, very low pH environments, and desiccation. For instance, botulism from canned foods *can* occur from eating the food (and toxin) directly - but you're supposed to throw it out if it look suspicious because even if you cook it and inactivate the toxin, the spores are still present after cooking. The spores can find anaerobic environments inside the body and germinate, then produce toxin afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

Clostridium botulinum toxin is present ubiquitously in soil. As such it is more than plausible that hay bails, which come into contact with soil can and I should expect almost probably will be infected with these bacteria. However it is not the mere presence of the bacteria itself which causes poisoning, it is the toxins they produce when the appropriate conditions are met. These toxins are produced as a consequence of spore formation.

Traditionally in human cases, the presence of toxins has been linked to home canned foods, where there is an anaerobic environment with a ph < 4.5 (http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/41/8/1167.full). It is conceivable that such an anaerobic environment exists within a hay bail (even if not wrapped). The following site from the ontario minestry agriculture and food (http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/livestock/horses/facts/info_haylage.htm) suggest that the pH certain methods of hay bailing have pH < 5. This would seemingly confirm hay as potential source for botulinum toxins.

With regards to testing the hay for C. botulinum I would expect there to be a very high chance of finding this, due to soil contamination, however this does not imply this was a definite source for poisoning. A more conclusive test would be for the toxin. So in summary it is logical to suggest that hay could be the toxin source, but this does not mean it was the source.

Comment: This is a very good answers, full of information.  I choose to award the bounty to @MCM as that answer more directly addresses the root question about the toxin surviving. Thank you both for your answers.